# bulk insert using sqlite and dapper

Tags: .net, sqlite, dapper

I am using dapper.net and sqlite. When I do this query only the first id is insert, the rest are ignored. How do I bulk insert?

```
insert or ignore into pair(key, value) 
    select @key, (select value from list where id in @id_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

A SELECT query without a FROM clause will generate a single record:

```sql
> SELECT 42;
42
```

When you put a subquery into that SELECT list, that subquery is a [scalar subquery](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#in_op), which returns only a single value.

To return a constant value for each record in a query, you have to put that constant into the SELECT clause of that query:

```sql
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO pair(key, value) 
SELECT @key, value FROM list WHERE id IN (1,2,3,...)
```